# How to delete parent a element completely

Tags: javascript

if this is my div element

```
<a href="sdfsfsf"><p class="quotes">blablabla</p></a>
```

If it is not homepage, how can you delete parent a for this `quotes`

i could not configure this code for my element:

```
function delete_row(e)
{
    e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode.parentNode);
}
```

js program must be automatically loaded also when page is loaded and it is not home page, it should delete a element

Comment: Are you intending to leave the `<p>` node in place?

Comment: Did you try something like: `delete_row(document.querySelector(".quotes"))"?

Comment: yes <p> must be leave in place

Answer (score 1):

To remove the immediate parent of a child element `e`, leaving the child still in the DOM (but reparented to its original grandparent), use [`.replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild):

```
e.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(e, e.parentNode);
```

Comment: for my case it would be so?

Comment: var x = document.getElementsByClassName("quotes");
x.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(x, x.parentNode);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave p in place you need to add it to its parent's container first:

```
function delete_row(e) {
    var parent = e.parentNode;
    var grandParent = parent.parentNode;
    // remove e from its parent
    e.remove();
    // insert e into its grandParent, before parent
    grandParent.insertBefore(e, parent);
    // remove parent
    parent.remove();
}
```

But the same can be accomplished by the solution of @Alnitak above.

Today I've learned :)